# How can I make child divs fill the space of parent div with margins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I have a set of child divs inside a parent div that has a set width. The elements are put together using isotope but I am not using an isotope layout mode as they were not working for me in terms of spacing.

What I am trying to do is have divs that fill the space of the parent so at the far right there are no gaps and that each div has a margin and padding. So far its working alright like so:

[image]

As you can see the divs have the correct margin right and top but what i want to do is stop the margin on the last items of each row. The issue here is that some of the divs have a different width. The alignment should but the same point as the top right box as you can see in the image.

The css I used is as follows:

```
.global-post{
    padding: 0;
    height: 400px;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 308px;
}
```

This creates the width of the narrower items and then the projects that are wider have different width values.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a fix for the issue?

Comment: Are there two type of divs? divs which can be 4 in a row, and divs which can be 2 in a row?

Answer (score 0):

Give a `negative left margin` to `row` like `margin-left: -20px` and add `left margin` to every `div` inside that `row` like `margin-left: 20px;`

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span">1</div>
      <div class="span">2</div>
      <div class="span">3</div>
      <div class="span">4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="span">1</div>
      <div class="span">2</div>
    </div>


    .row{
       margin-left: -20px;
    }

    .span{
       margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: There is no .row for each row, its just one div as a whole that wraps all the child divs

Comment: Then also you can try to use `margin-right: -20px`(or whatever the margin have between two divs) by adding to your `wrappper`